# Separating firstname and lastname using lastIndexof() in String class

Tags: java, string

I have written a code which separates first name and last name in a name String:

```
public class NameSeperator {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String custName="Your Name";
        int index;
        String firstName;

        index=custName.indexOf(" ");


        **int last=custName.lastIndexOf("")**;
        firstName=custName.substring(0,index);
        String lastName=custName.substring(index+1,last);

     // get the first name
        System.out.println("First Name = "+firstName);
        System.out.println("Last Name = "+lastName);
    }

}
```

I have used

```
int last=custName.lastIndexOf("")
```

and used only "" here but it takes complete string here.Is "" means the complete string at which a particular string method is called?

Comment: what´s wrong with your code, the output i am getting seems to be correct? By the way for the last name you can simply use `String#substring(int beginnindex)` since it will create a subststring from the index to the end.

Comment: change `lastName=custName.substring(index+1);` will print "Name"

Comment: My query is:  If I just put string symbol("") after lastIndexOf method than is it takes the complete string written above the method by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend this simplified version :

```
int index = custName.indexOf(' ');
String firstName = custName.substring(0, index);
String lastName = custName.substring(index + 1);
```

Note that `indexOf` searches for a single character. Also the second substring for `lastName` gets the remaining chars until the end.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly split it by space and then use array index

```
String name[] = custName.split(" ");
String firstName = name[0];
String lastName = name[1]
```

Comment: It will print wrong value if name contains middle name.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code :

```
  String custName="Your Name";

  int start = custName.indexOf(' ');
  int end = custName.lastIndexOf(' ');

  String firstName = "";
  String middleName = "";
  String lastName = "";

  if (start >= 0) {
      firstName = custName.substring(0, start);
      if (end > start)
          middleName = custName.substring(start + 1, end);
      lastName = custName.substring(end + 1, custName.length());
  }     

  System.out.println("First Name = "+firstName);
  System.out.println("Middle Name = "+middleName);
  System.out.println("Last Name = "+lastName);
```